# How to query from a derived table by using select object?

Tags: zend-framework2

I wanna implement a statement with select object in Zend Framework 2 like this:

```
select count(*) as total from ( select id from table group by name) a;
```

My code is :

```
$sub = $adapter->select()->from('table')->group('name');
$sql = $adapter->select()
->columns('total'->new Expression('count(*)'))
->from(array('a'=>$sub));
```

When I execute the query ,  browser always show me that  '$table must be a string, array, or an instance of TableIdentifier'.

Appreciate for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally,I resolved it by myself.

```
    $select1 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
    $select1->from('table')->columns('id')->group('name');

    $select2 = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
    $select2->columns('total'->new Expression('count(*)'))
    ->from(array('a'=>$select1));
```